# How to use AES CCM with Bouncycastle JCE provider - CCMParameters

Tags: java, encryption, aes, bouncycastle, jce

Is it possible to use JCE to perform CCM?

I see lots of examples on the Internet using the non-JCE bouncycastle classes. In particular, I see them calling init passing in a CCMParameters object.

Trouble is, this CCMParameters object doesn't derive from AlgorthmParameters or AlgorithmParameterSpec, so there seems to be no way to pass it into Cipher.init() (after getting a Cipher object with Cipher.getInstance("AES/CCM/NoPadding")).

How does one do this?

Comment: Necroed: for the BC _provider_ see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51834/can-java-decrypt-a-4-byte-mic (although it was voted offtopic there).

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is sample code for AES-CCM algo
where all usual names are input params.
take care about HEX data bytes and all other things

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.BlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESEngine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CCMBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.CCMParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

public class AesCcm {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalStateException, InvalidCipherTextException {
    int macSize = 125;
    byte[] key = new byte[32];
    byte[] keybyte = "test123".getBytes();
    byte[] inputNouc = "abcdefghijklm".getBytes();
    for (int I = 0; I < keybyte.length; I++) {
        key[I] = keybyte[I];
    }

//      Input data in HEX format
    String input = "ed88fe7b95fa0ffa190b7ab33933fa";

    byte[] inputData= Hex.decode(input);

    BlockCipher engine = new AESEngine();
    CCMParameters params = new CCMParameters(new KeyParameter(key),
            macSize, inputNouc, null);

    CCMBlockCipher cipher = new CCMBlockCipher(engine);
    cipher.init(true, params);
    byte[] outputText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(inputData.length)];
    int outputLen = cipher.processBytes(inputData, 0, inputData.length,
            outputText , 0);
    cipher.doFinal(outputText, outputLen);

//      outputText and mac are in bytes 
    System.out.println(outputText);
    System.out.println(cipher.getMac());
    }
}
```

Comment: So that's nice, but the question was about using JCE, not the bouncycastle proprietary API.

Answer (score -1):

No, the JCE currently (as of JDK 10) does not support CCM mode.

For the list of supported AES modes, please have a look at the official documentation from Oracle [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/oracle-providers.htm). Look at the Table 4-13 *"The SunJCE Provider Cipher Transformations"*

Comment: Perhaps this deserves a new question, but the comment on the question above suggests that using BC and the ordinary JCE APIs that this might now be possible. As noted below, I know BC proprietary APIs can do it, but it would be nice if the JCE API had a way even if it requires an alternative Cipher provider.